# exceptions.ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Tags: python, regex, json, scrapy

I have some Scrapy code that crawls a website using a Regex to look for some non standard source code in the form of a dictionary containing data that I am looking for. When this is found the data is printed to screen.

The table containing this data that the user sees has multiple tabs. When the user moves between tabs, an XHR request refreshes the data in the background. The second part of the code attempts to print the dictionary returned when the user moves from the 'Overall' to 'Home' tab at the following page:

http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/

The code is here:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time
import re
import json
import requests


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 5

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\Teams'),deny=(),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        match1 = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") \
                     + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body) #regex to match inital data item


        if match1 is not None:
            playerdata1 = match1.group(1) #if match1 isnt empty then print the dictionary embedded in the source code of the page

            print '**********Players by team (Summary - Overall):**********'
            print '-' * 170
            for player in json.loads(playerdata1):

                print ("{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name}".decode().format(**player))


            #submit xhr request to obtain the dictionary that contains the 'Home' data, rather than the 'Overall' data embedded in the source code.
            url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed'
            params = {
            'field': '1',
            'isAscending': 'false',
            'orderBy': 'Rating',
            'playerId': '-1',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'teamId': '32'
            }
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/Teams/32/'}

            response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

            fixtures = response.json()
            print '**********Players by team (Summary - Home):**********'
            print '-' * 170

            for player in json.loads(fixtures): #print 'Home' dictionary here:

                print ("{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name}".decode().format(**player))

execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal2'])
```

This code throws up an error saying that a string or buffer is expected. When I have tried converting the variable 'fixtures' to a string before being used in the statement `for player in json.loads(fixtures):` I get an error saying:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
exceptions.ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

I'm assuming that the error is in relation to the statement `.decode().format(**player))`, but I'm not sure what this needs changing to.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: `fixtures` is a python object already. Why are you passing the elements in that to `json.loads()` **again**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to decode objects that are *already decoded*. That is what `response.json()` took care of already.

Just loop over the `fixtures` list *without* passing them to `json.loads()`:

```
for player in fixtures:
```

You can drop the `.decode()` method and use a `u'...'` unicode string literal instead:

```
print u"{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name}".format(**player)
```

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not a function, unless you used `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your module.

For your sample URL, headers and parameters, this produces:

```
>>> fixtures = response.json()
>>> for player in fixtures: 
...     print u"{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name}".format(**player)
... 
32,81726,Phil Jones
32,137795,Tyler Blackett
32,8166,Ashley Young
32,18296,Antonio Valencia
32,22079,Jonny Evans
32,23110,Ángel Di María
32,25363,Juan Mata
32,71345,Chris Smalling
32,5835,Darren Fletcher
32,107941,Michael Keane
32,79554,David de Gea
32,69956,Tom Cleverley
32,3859,Wayne Rooney
32,21723,Anderson
32,4564,Robin van Persie
32,39308,Danny Welbeck
32,130334,Adnan Januzaj
```